# NotifyIcon stays longer than I input

Tags: c#

I am currently using this code:

```cs
public void SendNotification(System.Drawing.Icon icon, System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon tooltipicon, string title, string description, int timeout)
{
    // sendNotification(System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information, System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info, "a", "b", 5000);

    var notification = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();

    notification.Visible = true;
    notification.Icon = icon;
    notification.Text = description;
    notification.BalloonTipIcon = tooltipicon;
    notification.BalloonTipTitle = title;
    notification.BalloonTipText = description;
    notification.BalloonTipClosed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        notification.Icon.Dispose();
        notification.Dispose();
    };
    notification.ShowBalloonTip(timeout);
}
```

And calling it like this:

```cs
SendNotification(System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information, System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info, "a", "b", 5000);
```

I set the timeout to 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) but the notification stays a lot longer. Does anyone know why?

Comment: there no way your method to know 5000 is milisecond or not. you set it by int, it is not not true

Comment: According to [the documentation of `ShowBalloonTip(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_NotifyIcon_ShowBalloonTip_System_Int32_), "This parameter (`timeout`) is deprecated as of Windows Vista. Notification display times are now based on system accessibility settings."

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip?view=netcore-3.1

We see 2 things that are applicable:

> ### Parameters
>
> timeout - int32
> This parameter is deprecated as of Windows Vista. Notification display times are now based on system accessibility settings.

We also see:

> ### Remarks
>
> Minimum and maximum timeout values are enforced by the operating system and are typically 10 and 30 seconds, respectively, however this can vary depending on the operating system. Timeout values that are too large or too small are adjusted to the appropriate minimum or maximum value. In addition, if the user does not appear to be using the computer (no keyboard or mouse events are occurring) then the system does not count this time towards the timeout.

From this, we can conclude that if you call the function with the timeout set to 5 seconds, it's going to ignore it and use the 10-second minimum. If you want 5 seconds you'll need to find some other way of showing your notification.

Comment: the "timeout" is just how i declare/define it. even if i change it to anything else like "duration" it still doesnt work.

Comment: @JasonKaranikYT `timeout` is the formal name of the parameter.  The Remarks apply to that parameter whether you use the same name for the actual parameter or not.

Comment: so what do i do to fix it

Comment: If you use the [OS notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area) then you get the OS-provided behavior, which is user-configurable (notification duration, quiet hours, etc).  If you don't like the behavior of the OS-provided notifications, you'll have to make your own.  In this particular case, you can probably make your own timeout by setting a timer and then telling the OS notification to close when the timer fires.

Comment: i am confused. is there a way to fix my current code so it works according to the timeout/duration?

Comment: @JasonKaranikYT - The documentation I cited explains that the operating system is typically enforcing a 10 second minimum and 30 second maximum AND that if the user appears to the OS to be "away" that the timer isn't running. If you call the function with the timeout set to 5 seconds, it's going to ignore it and use the 10-second minimum. If you want 5 seconds you'll need to find some other way of showing your notification.